# How to find the number of cells that one point can be in?

Tags: plotting, graphics, drawing

I draw the attached plot drawn with the following code. Each color represents a cell. How can I find the average number of cells that one user (any point within the square) can be in? By average I mean "the user can be anywhere within the whole area". For example, averaging over 10000 random locations of a point within the square area.

[image]

```
 ell = t [Function] t^-20.75];500, 2}]; 
 H = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 50]; 
 r = Table[H[[i]] ell[Norm[{x, y} - X[[i]]]], {i, 1, 20}]; 
 s = Table[r[[i]]/( Total[Delete[r, i]] + 30.99), {i, 1, 20}]; 

 Show[Table[
 RegionPlot[s[[i]] >= 0.1, {x, -0.7, 0.7}, {y, -0.7, 0.7}, 
 MaxRecursion -> 2, PlotPoints -> 40, 
 PlotStyle -> {FaceForm[{Opacity[0.5], ColorData[97][i]}]}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> ColorData[97][i]], {i, 1, 20}], Graphics[Point[X]]]
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier (and more correct) to sum up the areas of the shaded regions (with multiplicity) and to divide the result by the area of the square?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, seems to be a very good idea. But I do not know how to do it. I really appreciate if you can help me on this.

Comment: `Sum[Area@ImplicitRegion[f >= 0.1, {{x, -0.7, 0.7}, {y, -0.7, 0.7}}],{f, s}]/(2 0.7)^2`? See also the documentation of `Area` for a detailed explanation of the options of `Area` that allow you to control the accuracy of the computation (`AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal`).

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Thanks a lot. It seems to be computationally very expensive approach. Is there any alternative way that you can think of!!

Comment: Why do you think so? It is not more expensive to compute an approximate area of an impicit region than computing an approximate triangle mesh via `RegionPlot`. Basically that is what `Area` does: It meshes the domain and sums the triangle areas.

Comment: I'd like to point out that I had to resort to wild guessing because you did not supply the definition of `s`...

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher   ell = t \[Function] t^-3.75];
X = RandomReal[{-0.7, 0.7}, {20, 2}];
H = RandomVariate[ExponentialDistribution[1], 20];
r = Table[H[[i]] ell[Norm[{x, y} - X[[i]]]], {i, 1, 20}];
s = Table[r[[i]]/( Total[Delete[r, i]] + 3.99), {i, 1, 20}];

Comment: Better to put such information into the post (you can _edit_ it). And `n`, `NN`, and `ell` are still undefined.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher, Pease have a look at my updated question.

Comment: You could create a bounding area hierarchy (a tree of bounding boxes), or alternatively a quadtree, which would accelerate Henrik's approach of checking a very large number of points against all regions, (assuming the regions are not all completely on top of each other). This has the advantage of logarithmic lookup for a point and avoiding checking points against regions which are clearly too distant.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a Monte-Carlo approach could look like this. There is a considerable amount of number crunching involved, so we better compile the working horse function:

```
cf = Compile[{{H, _Real, 1}, {X1, _Real, 1}, {X2, _Real, 1}, {Z, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{n, R, r, x1, x2},
    x1 = Compile`GetElement[Z, 1];
    x2 = Compile`GetElement[Z, 2];
    r = H ((X1 - x1)^2 + (X2 - x2)^2)^-1.875;
    R = Total[r] + 3.99;
    Total[UnitStep[r - (0.1/1.1) R]]
    ]
   ,
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

Now:

```
pts = RandomReal[{-0.7, 0.7}, {10000000, 2}];
{X1, X2} = Transpose[X];
N@Mean@cf[H, X1, X2, pts]
```

> 2.05869

The function `cf` counts how many entries of the vector `s` are above `0.1` for a given `{x,y} = Z`. Applying `cf` in a listable way to all elements of `pts` and taking the mean yields the empirical average number of satisfied inequalities.